# python with beautifulsoup - remove tags

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am doing some python program to extract lyrics

the code i use:

```
    import urllib
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    url = urllib.urlopen("http://www.lyricsnmusic.com/david-bowie/slip-away-lyrics/22143075")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(url.read())
    print soup.find('pre', itemprop='description')
```

the result gets me what i need but with the extra of the tag
for example : `<pre item="description>` then the lyrics
anyone know how to get only the lyrics?
the structure puts the lyrics between the pre tag
thanks in advance

Comment: Are you looking for `soup.find('pre', itemprop='description').contents[0]`?

Comment: do you know how can i write this lyrics into a file?

Answer (score 0):

Use the text attribute of the node that you've found

```
import urllib
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
url = urllib.urlopen("http://www.lyricsnmusic.com/david-bowie/slip-away-lyrics/2
2143075")
soup = BeautifulSoup(url.read())
desc=soup.find('pre', itemprop='description')
print desc.text
```